# How to find the number of elements in a pointer array?

Tags: c

What are the different ways to find the number of elements in a int array pointer which is allocated with malloc?

int* a = malloc(...)

Comment: You have to _remember_ the size (e.g.) `size_t acount = 23; int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * acount);` Then, `acount` is the number of elements. You can automate this somewhat with a struct: `struct arr { size_t acount; int *a; }; struct arr myarr;` Then, you can pass around `&myarr` to functions and they have access to the count and the array data from a single argument. You can even resize (with `realloc`) and make the array larger.

Comment: You can't. Andrei Alexandrescu in [one of hi talks](https://youtu.be/LIb3L4vKZ7U) says this is one of memory allocator design flows.

Comment: look in between the parens after malloc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't if you define `a` to be a plain pointer to the first element in the array. An alternative is to make the size of the array part of the type.  So, instead of defining `a` to be a pointer to an `int`, you could make it a pointer to an `int[size]`.

It makes it a little cumbersome to work with though since you need to dereference it when you use it.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Size(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof *(x))

int main() {
    
    int(*a)[10] = malloc(sizeof *a);       // the size made part of a's type

    for(unsigned i=0; i < Size(*a); ++i) {
        (*a)[i] = i;                       // note: not  a[i]  but  (*a)[i] 
    }

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof *a);  // prints 40 if sizeof(int) is 4
    printf("%zu\n", Size(*a));   // prints 10

    free(a);
}
```

Comment: Well it's accepted, so I guess it's what OP was looking for. A problem with this technique is the real PITA you'll have with dealing with any pointer-expecting interfaces (and there tend to be a lot) - there's going to be be lot of punctuation. The size won't follow the pointer through any of those interfaces, either, which leaves you rewriting your whole program to deal with specific-sized array pointers? Unlikely to be a successful result.

Comment: @CarlNorum Thank you for input! Yes, I agree. Perhaps I should have written _very cumbersome_ instead of _a little cumbersome_ to emphasize that one will have to depickle `a` when using it with all typical API:s, like `foo(*a, Size(*a));` for a function wanting a pointer to the first element and the array length - and no, I wouldn't suggest using a different API for functions one writes even when using this alternative approach inside a function. A pointer and the length is idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

There are zero ways to do that outside of keeping track of it separately from the allocation.

Comment: Can you may be explain it with a example? Is there is no way for us to find out other than that? Is there any functions or for example sizeof operator or something>?

Comment: No, there are no functions or operators (`sizeof` or otherwise) that can help you. An allocated pointer is nothing but a pointer.

Comment: @laura `malloc` returns a pointer to an area large enough to hold the requested number of bytes.  There is no magic incantation that will divine the number of bytes it returned from that pointer.  The usual way to keep track is to store the allocated size in a separate variable.